# Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain calling AzMan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, appdomain, azman

In an ASP.NET MVC web application, I'm seeing the following error occaisionally:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded
>   appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131014)    at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.InternalGetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32
>   hr, IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis)    at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32 hr,
>   IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis)    at
>   Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles.IAzApplication.OpenOperation(String
>   bstrOperationName, Object varReserved)

The line in code where this exception is thrown is this one:

```
IAzOperation operation = _azManApp.OpenOperation(operationName);
```

Most of the time, the code works fine. When the error happens, it seems to reoccur a fair bit, such that recycling the AppPool is the only good remedy.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this happens? I've gotten this a few times but it would always be that the resource (Operation, Task, etc.) didn't exist or my connection string to AzMan was incorrect.

Comment: No - it's still an error we see. Often just reloading the page again and it works.

Comment: That's too bad. I no longer get the error. What are the other patterns that you're noticing when it happens? Because before, I only noticed it when the Operation didn't exist or I didn't called .UpdateCache() before I query the AzManStore. I've also migrated to storing the data in SQL rather than XML.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same issue and stumbled across the [following link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1804768.aspx/1)

To summarize it appears that there is a folder change notification process that as you get more files/folder in your application it starts causing some timing issues.  There is a link in the linked article that points toward a hotfix for the issue.

Comment: Hard to tell if they are related. The KB article linked to from that forum post (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272) only mentions .NET 2.0 and we're using 4.0, but there could be something in that.

Comment: I noticed that too, but the behavior seemed real close.  And, after reading the article I did think back and realized that the error started occurring after adding quite a bit a functionality to the app, which of course corresponds to more files involved.